# Curl return 'Empty reply from server'

Tags: php, php-curl

I need to extract an HTTPS page from my server and with cURL print the error 'Empty reply from server'.
This is my code:

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array('HTTP_ACCEPT: Something', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: fr, en, da, nl, it', 'HTTP_CONNECTION: Something');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gibbohotel.it/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

Is it a proxy problem of the external server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This specific site refuses curl queries - a command line query returns the same result. So you have to pretend your're using some other user agent with [CURLOPT_USERAGENT](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

```
<?php
$ch = curl_init();
$headers = array('HTTP_ACCEPT: Something', 'HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE: fr, en, da, nl, it', 'HTTP_CONNECTION: Something');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://gibbohotel.it/');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1 );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
$result = curl_exec( $ch );
if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}
curl_close($ch);
?>
```

*However, this site might have reasons for not getting harvested via curl or similar means, so don't complain, if you do so an get blocked...*